# Android service connection via JSON to MS SQL backend

Tags: android, sql, json, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I and a colleague of mine are making an Android app for a bachelor project, and are not aware of what we should use in order to connect an Android device to an MS SQL database. The possible options we have considered so far are either using MVC4, WCF or Web API. We are trying to send just a bunch of strings from the database to the Android device, but we do not have extensive knowledge about either of the fore-mentioned technologies and we are wondering what is the best way and how to go about it all. We are also not aiming at creating a webpage for the project, and thus we think that MVC might be an overkill.

Thank you and we are looking towards your thoughts about this!

Comment: what are you using for building the app? are you using android SDK?

Comment: For the Android app yes we are using Android SDK and Eclipse, and for the backend we are using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Use web services, it is the best way